# How to PayPal do_direct_payment in the Philippines

Tags: paypal

After I am searching for the past few days and I find out that Do Direct Payment by PayPal is not available to all Filipinos merchants, but I need direct payment using cards, there is any suggestion please of how I can place cards payment on my website. Please be patient with me. :)

Comment: Payments Pro is not available for accounts outside the US, UK, or Canada.  You'll need to find a merchant account provider that works in the Filipinos.

Comment: Thanks you for the reply, but do know another way to implement card payment? Any other except PayPal.